# Symmetric Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K,$ with a non-degenerate scalar product. Let $v_{0}, w_{0}$ be elements of $V .$ Let $A : V \rightarrow V$ be the linear map such that $A(v)=\left\langle v_{0}, v\right\rangle w_{0} .$ Describe $^{t} A$.

Solution. We have

$$
\langle A(v), w\rangle=\left\langle v_{0}, v\right\rangle\left\langle w_{0}, w\right\rangle=\left\langle v,\left\langle w_{0}, w\right\rangle v_{0}\right\rangle
$$

So
 $$
^{t} A(w)=\left\langle w_{0}, w\right\rangle v_{0}
$$.

**My question is**: I didn't understand the notation of $\langle A(v), w\rangle$, what is this mean? Can you explain? And so that how did you get this: $
\langle A(v), w\rangle=\left\langle v_{0}, v\right\rangle\left\langle w_{0}, w\right\rangle=\left\langle v,\left\langle w_{0}, w\right\rangle v_{0}\right\rangle
$ ? Can you explain? Thanks...

Comment: Isn't $\langle A(v),w\rangle$ the scalar product (on $V$) between $Av$ and $w$? For your second question, just use the definition of $A$...

Comment: @weirdo can you give definition of $\langle A(v), w\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A (v)=\left\langle v_{0}, v\right\rangle w_{0}$ is a vector in $V $. So it is perfect to take the scalar product between $A (v)$ and $w $, which is $\langle A(v), w\rangle$.

Note that $$\langle A(v), w\rangle=\langle\left\langle v_{0}, v\right\rangle w_{0},w\rangle=\left\langle v_{0}, v\right\rangle\left\langle w_{0}, w\right\rangle.$$
This follows directly from the property of scalar product. $$\langle cv, w\rangle=\langle v, cw\rangle=c\langle v, w\rangle.$$

Comment: Thanks for answer.